# Encrypt only the content of an image file not entire file

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, bit-manipulation

I am creating an APP and need to encript only the content of an image. I need that the file was still an image after conversion, but the image showed does not show as the original.

For example, I will send the image encrypted to other user and this one will be able to show and image (but not the original), but the original image was encrypted in that file.

With the following algorythm I encrypted the entire file, and this cannot be opened as image due the header is encrypted as well.

I am using this algorythm but I do not know how to only encrypt data or how to add/modify the headers of an image in java/android:

```
public byte[] encrypt_image(Bitmap bm, String password_) {

    byte[] encryptedData = null;

    try{
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();  

        byte[] keyStart = password_.getBytes();
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
        sr.setSeed(keyStart);
        kgen.init(128, sr); 
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] key = skey.getEncoded();    

        // Encrypt
        encryptedData = Security.encrypt(key,b);


    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("encrpyt_image()", e.getMessage());
    }
    return encryptedData;
}
```

Anyone has an idea about how to codify that, I've been searching in internet with no success.

Comment: I have to admit, I don't understand the question. You want to encrypt an image into another image (with obviously more or less white noise content?), or you want to hide an extra image in an existing image file?

Comment: I want to encrypt an image and the if you open on a image viewer you will se noise. With my codification I encrypt the entire file, so the image viewer cannot open the file (.png, .jpeg...) because the header information is encrypted as well.

Comment: what is the point of being able to open the file if it's just noise?

Comment: Look at the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html . Use copyPixelsToBuffer and copyPixelsFromBuffer

Comment: Convert the bitmap "image content" to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` (extract it from the bitmap first), encrypt that and then append the unmodified header somehow? Are you asking how to do this or something similar?

Comment: I want to open the file with just noise, right now I cannot open the image because once is encrypted "is not an image anymore".

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I am trying to attach headers but I have not find the way to extract header, encrypt image pixels, and attach header to result of encrypt.

Comment: @SpiderPig do you have some example about how to do that. I am pretty newbie in Android :(

Comment: This is probably silly and not worth bothering with because either SSL is easier or if you do use AES like this, the key is in the code, and you're not really protecting anything in a meaningful way.

Comment: @David Can you elaborate on the fact that the key is still in the code?

Comment: @JohnAndrews If the use case is securely sending an image to a different user in a way that the service can't see the image, you need some sort of PKI. If there's just a shared password between users, you should at least use bcrypt, scrypt, or PBKDF2. Meanwhile, the `Security` class should be using some sort of block chaining. But unless you care about the service seeing the image, it's a lot easier and safer to just post the image over HTTPS, then fetch it over HTTPS, with the service doing access control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the get/setPixels methods may be the easiest way to do this.

```
int[] pixels = new int[bm.getWidth() * bm.getHeight()];
bm.getPixels(pixels, 0, bm.getWidth(), 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight()); 
encryptIntArray(pixels);
bm.setPixels(pixels, 0, bm.getWidth(), 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
```

Now you just have to write the encryptIntArray method.

edit:
You could also try to use a ByteBuffer, then you don't have to do the conversion.

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(bm.getByteCount());
bm.copyPixelsToBuffer(bb);
byte[] b = bb.array();
bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(Security.encrypt(key,b)));
```

I haven't tested that code though.

Comment: Note that saving the image to JPG or any other format that changes the picture will break such encryption. Also "encrypted" image will not be compressable *at all* (well, maybe by 0.5%).

Comment: Do you have some example about how to convert int[] to byte[], my algorithm returns a byte[] and all the conversion methods I have tried does not work. :(

Comment: Excelent, that works perfectly. I am really grateful ;)