# Encrypting an image to form another image?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Is there a way to encrypt an image in Java so that another image is formed? I'm now using the following code:

```
Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES");    
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
enFile=cipher.doFinal(bFile);
```

But the resulting file cannot be opened without decrypting. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862143/encrypt-only-the-content-of-an-image-file-not-entire-file) in stackoverflow but it is in Android and I couldn't implement it in Java.

Can anyone please suggest a way to implement this in Java or any other way to convert an image into another using AES encryption?

Comment: Aren't you looking for [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)?

Comment: @fge Actually iam doing steganography in next stage, before that i have to encrypt the image and then hide the message in that encrypted image.

Comment: Uh, I'd do these operations in the reverse order: "steganpgraph" the message into the image, _and then_ encrypt. Any reason why you need to do it the way you want to do?

Comment: @fge yes because iam trying to implement this project:http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6496492&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D6496492

Comment: Eh, I see... Good luck ;)

Comment: "*But it is in android and I couldn't implement it in java*" > Not sure I understand this - what part of the linked question could you not implement in standard Java?