# How to manipulate image data

Tags: java, image, encryption, stream

Is there a way to tell the offset that would be required to edit an images data while leaving its file structure in tact, or is that information on a per file extension basis. For example, opening an image file as a byte stream but only encrypting the actual image data portion while leaving the header data intact.

Comment: Most file formats are described somewhere. Have you tried googling some?

Comment: What do you mean by `file structure` exactly?

Comment: Yes, most formats have difference specifications, I didn't want to write it extension dependent, thus my question as to whether there was a method somewhere that can detect where image data begins.

Comment: @Eypros
The header information in an image that determines filetype etc..

Comment: I don't think you will find a good way to do that: most image formats are compressed one way or another, so you cannot simply "edit" the content without decoding the content, and coding again, rendering all header information you had originally useless.

Comment: Very related: [Encrypt only the content of an image file not entire file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862143/encrypt-only-the-content-of-an-image-file-not-entire-file)